# Not able to print { codec => rubydebug } in the separate file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

```
output {
  elasticsearch { 
     hosts => "localhost:8812" 
     index =>"test_span_qry_one"
     document_id =>"%{cotid}"
     #document_type="_doc"

  }        
  file {
     path => C:/Soft/ES3/ELK_stack_7.4.2/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-7.4.2/temp.txt
     codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

This is my code in the config file of logstash.

> [ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, { at line 58, column 15 (byte 2760) after output {\r\n  elasticsearch {..........

Comment: Which is line number 58? Or can you add the complete pipeline conf file.

Comment: You're missing quotes around the path parameter of the file output, like this: `path => "C:/Soft/ES3/ELK_stack_7.4.2/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-7.4.2/temp.txt"`

Comment: Yes...@baudsp..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 file {
     path => "C:/Soft/ES3/ELK_stack_7.4.2/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-7.4.2/temp.txt"
     codec => rubydebug
 }
```

This is the correct syntax ..path should be in double qoutes.